# insertion sort in c programming

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, insertion-sort

In insertion sort,

- how can we insert a new integer into an array of integers?
- The memory for the array will be allocated during compilation,so we cannot increase the size of array,Even if we allocate some extra space,what should we do if the required memory exceeds the allocated memory?
- should we create a new array for the insertion of each and every integer?
- What should we do if we want insert more number of integers into the sorted array?
- Can we do this with pointers?

Comment: This contains too many questions, and is unclear. Please be more specific. Your question seems to relate more to dynamic allocation of arrays than to insertion sort.

Comment: I think you need to grab some online material on C / books and read up on memory allocation for variables, arrays etc and just C programming in general. The axiom that the memory is allocated during compilation is just not right.

Comment: I asked about the same point many times to be more and more specific,not different questions.Might be it is related to dynamic memory allocation, but i am asking about insertion sort @robjb

Comment: I am here for a solution,if I am wrong,say that I am wrong.I dont want any personal suggestion@Andrew

Comment: Please don't post your homework assignments here and expect us to give you the answers without you showing anything that you have done to figure out the answer on your own.

Comment: @Rajesh - the suggestion is not personal - it's (good) advice. If your understanding of memory within c programming is unclear, then you should set yourself the task of finding out more and learning more about it - books, online material etc. You will feel far more satisfied from solving the problem thru learning - than having an answer given to you that you do not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all the questions you asked can be answered by the following:

1. It is **not** true - in more than one sense - that the memory that holds arrays is allocated during compilation.

   1. The memory cannot be allocated before you actually run the program.
   2. While the size of an array is usually decided at compilation (e. g. `int array[32]`), the same is not true for pointers.

      For example, `int *array = malloc(many * sizeof(int));` makes room for `many` integers.
2. While it **is** true that you cannot increase the amount of memory allocated for an array, the same does **not** hold for pointers.

   For example, `array = realloc(many_more * sizeof(int));` makes room for `many_more` integers.

I suggest you read [this tutorial on pointers and arrays](http://home.earthlink.net/~momotuk/pointers.pdf).

Comment: It does not make room for `many` integers if `many` happens to be `SIZE_MAX/sizeof(int)+1`... ;-)